# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, array

Estoy intentando que una operación se repita con for pero al momento de correr el programa me arroja el error ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] entiendo que al coloar el dato "prendas" int debería poder ser comparable

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char nombre[20];
    int sueldo,dias;
    cout << " ¿Cuales el nombre del vendedor?" << endl;
    cin >> nombre ;
    cout << " ¿Cuales el sueldo base del vendedor?"<< endl;
    cin >> sueldo;
    cout << " ¿Cuantos dias trabajo?"<< endl;
    cin >> dias;
    int  prendas[dias],total[dias];
    for (int i=0;i<dias;i++)
    cout << " ¿Cuantas prendas vendio este dia?"<< endl;
    cin >> prendas[dias];
    for (int j=0;j<dias;j++)
    if (prendas<4)
        total=sueldo;
        else if (prendas<9)
            total = (prendas*25)+sueldo;
        else if (prendas<13)
         total = (prendas*45)+sueldo;
            else
         total = (prendas*70)+sueldo;}

     for (int h=0;h<n;h++){
        cout << prendas;total
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En la línea `int  prendas[dias],total[dias];` estás declarando 2 arreglos. Deberías obtener un error ya que sus tamaños deben conocerse en tiempo de compilación. Si quieres un arreglo dinámico, estás en C++, usa [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) y [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) para cadenas de caracteres.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí estás declarando un array:

```
int  prendas[dias];
```

Aunque no es un error como tal, este array no es conforme al estándar. Los arrays deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, y en este caso el tamaño del array no se conoce hasta que no se está ejecutando el programa. Es lo que se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array).

Al ser una característica no contemplada en el estándar, que te funcione dependerá únicamente del compilador que estés usando en ese momento, es decir, si tratas de compilar este mismo programa en otra máquina, es posible que empiecen a salir errores y que no puedas generar el ejecutable.

Para evitar esto puedes usar memoria dinámica

```
int * prendas = new int[dias];
```

O contenedores de la STL

```
std::vector<int> prendas(dias);
```

Hablando ahora de los errores. Ya hemos dicho que `prendas` es un array. Los problemas vienen cuando lo tratas como un entero:

```
if (prendas < 4)
```

`prendas` es un array, elemento el cual decae a puntero, es decir, la operación equivalente sería la siguiente:

```
int* ptr = prendas;
int value = 4;

if (ptr < value)
```

No puedes comparar punteros con enteros. Primero porque C++ posee un tipado fuerte, y segundo porque estás comparando valores que no tienen nada que ver entre ellos:

- Un puntero es un tipo de variable que almacena direcciones de memoria. No tiene sentido comparar una dirección de memoria con un 4
- El número de bytes que ocupa un puntero depende en exclusiva de la arquitectura del sistema (32 bits, 64 bits, ...), mientras que en el caso de los enteros, éstos ocupan típicamente 32 bits, aunque en algunas arquitecturas pueden ser de solo 16 bits. No tiene sentido comparar así alegremente tipos de diferente tamaño porque no van a poder almacenar los mismos conjuntos de valores.

Tu aquí quieres comprobar cuántas prendas se han vendido un día determinado ... tienes, por tanto, que acceder al elemento del array que necesitas en ese momento. El día en cuestión te lo da la variable `j`

```
if (prendas[j] < 4)
```

Y lo mismo para los otros chequeos.

Como apunte final, no estaría de más encerrar el código del bucle `for` entre llaves. Aunque implícitamente la secuencia de `if-else` al completo quedará dentro del `for`, usar las llaves dejará el código más legible. También puedes aprovechar para corregir la tabulación

```
for (int j=0;j<dias;j++)
{
    if (prendas[j]<4)
        total[j] = sueldo;
    else if (prendas[j]<9)
        total[j] = (prendas[j]*25)+sueldo;
    else if (prendas[j]<13)
        total[j] = (prendas[j]*45)+sueldo;
    else
        total[j] = (prendas[j]*70)+sueldo;
}
```